# MKL BLAS functions not behaving as expected

Tags: c, visual-c++, intel-mkl

I can't get Intel MKL to work as it should from C. 
I have the following test program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include"mkl.h"
int main()
{
    int one = 1;
    int ten = 10;
    double copy[10];
    double threes[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) threes[i] = 3;

    dcopy(&ten, threes, &one, copy, &one);
    double l1norm;
    l1norm = dasum(&ten, threes, &one);
    return 0;
}
```

which is building and linking fine but not doing what I intended. Specifically  at the return line the array "copy" continues to be full of what was there when it was declared and l1norm equal to 0. 
I am linking to the libraries : mkl_blas95_ilp64.lib, mkl_core_dll.lib, mkl_intel_ilp64_dll.lib and mkl_intel_thread_dll.lib.

I'm also getting similar problems when running third-party code that calls MKL so I assume the problem is how I have the build configured (in Visual Studio 2015).

The equivalent Fortran program runs fine.

Comment: Have you tried to use cblas API rather than Fortan API in your C code?

Comment: @Eric I have now.
If I replace the line` dcopy...` with `cblas_dcopy(10,threes,copy1)`then that line throws `Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` after managing to copy the first 3. Also the code I need to call (SuperLU) uses the Fortran declarations with "extern"
`cblas_dasum` actually seems to work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the libraries you link when porting from Fortran to C/C++. MKL requires different libraries and compiling flags with different compilers and settings. At least `mkl_blas95_ilp64.lib` is not required with C compiler.

Also ILP64 is not common compared to the default model LP64.

MKL Link Line Advisor is a tool provided by Intel to solve this issue. You could use it to check if your libraries and compiling flags are correct.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor

Comment: ilp64 library expects long long int .

Comment: yep, thanks. I had actually used the Link Line Advisor to work out what I needed in Fortran then copied those over without really thinking about it.